# Azure error adding source for QnA Chatbot

Tags: azure, azure-qna-maker

I am in the Language Studio > Custom question answering portal (https://language.cognitive.azure.com/questionAnswering/projects), trying to add a source to my existing Knowledge Base, but continuously get the error, "BadArgument Invalid input. See details." I've received this same error trying to add pdfs, word docs and csv files.

There is no link to see more details, just the text box that later disappears. I've been able to add documents this way when I had the free trial of azure, but since updating to a paid account 1/13/22 have had this error. Has anyone else received this error before?

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing the same issue. I tried with multiple data sources and different files, and it seems to break after adding 3 sources and trying to add a fourth. I am following up with Microsoft and will share what I learn.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).